# TFS WorkItemRelation Attributes Object?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

In reference to this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item%20template?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1#workitemrelation

At the bottom of the page, the description of the WorkItemRelation is:

**WorkItemRelation**

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
+    Name    +  Type  +           Description          +
+------------+--------+--------------------------------+
+------------+--------+--------------------------------+
+ attributes + object + Collection of link attributes. +
+------------+--------+--------------------------------+
+     rel    + string + Relation type.                 +
+------------+--------+--------------------------------+
+     url    + string + Link url                       + 
+------------+--------+--------------------------------+
```

What is the attributes object? I can not find the definition of it. Has anyone used the TFS api enough to be familiar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute is the object type which helps us to identify the detailed properties of the workitem relationship types,

You can easily get the definition of the attributes from [Work Item Relation Types API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20relation%20types/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1)

**Example:**

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "usage": "workItemLink",
    "editable": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "acyclic": true,
    "directional": true,
    "singleTarget": false,
    "topology": "tree",
    "isForward": true,
    "oppositeEndReferenceName": "System.LinkTypes.Duplicate-Reverse"
  },
  "referenceName": "System.LinkTypes.Duplicate-Forward",
  "name": "Duplicate",
  "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItemRelationTypes/System.LinkTypes.Duplicate-Forward"
}
```

The `Attributes` consist of the following JSON elements,

- usage
- editable
- enabled
- acyclic
- directional
- singleTarget
- topology
- isForward
- oppositeEndreferenceName